# Remote access not working without connected monitor

Tags: display, bios, windows-server-2008

I am trying to configure a Windows Server 2008 as a Home Server for my personal use (mainly for storing documents, hosting source-control, etc.).
The "server" consists of an Intel Atom 2700DC board and an Intel SSD.

Configuring remote access to the server, I am confronted with a very strange problem: As long as a monitor is connected to my server, remote access works without any problems.
However, when no monitor is connected at boot-time, remote access simply won't work (I keep getting errors when trying to connect that the remote server was not found or that remote access is disabled).

Windows definitely boots when no monitor is connected as I receive a message asking me whether to enter safe mode when booting after powering the server down by plugging the power cord.
When I plug in a monitor after boot, it stays turned off and remote desktop connections still fail.

Do you have any ideas about what I could try?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with the same board. I connected the Ethernet port of the board directly to a Linux machine to observe the behavior during boot. The server sends the usual Netbios broadcasts, then dies. It doesn't respond to ARP requests after this point.

Maybe a dummy plug connected to an HDMI to VGA converter would work. I'm still looking for a software solution.

Comment: I got it working playing around with the BIOS settings (disabling some fast-boot settings, ...). I can't, however, look up, how exactly I have set them because this would mean connecting a monitor which I have not available where the server is located ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a BIOS, problem is in GRUB2. Then it detects no video it stops booting process. Set GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT=console to disable this.

Comment: Well - as in my case it's Windows we are talking about, I tend to disagree ;-)
For other systems, this might be helpful, though.